# What is the best and simplest file type to use to read and run a pick and place program c#?

Tags: c#, csv, robotics

I´m working on making a C# program to control a 3-axis pick and place machine and trying to figure out which type of file type I want to use to read and run the pick and place program.
The program would look something like this:

Move X to 999.9
Wait for input 1
Move Y to 1.0
Set output 1
And simple things like that.

So I figure that in a CSV file it would look like this:

```
move,x,999.9
wait,in,1
move,y,1.0
set,out,1
```

And then I would have to check whats in the first column in the first line, if its move then check which axis in the second column then where to move in the last column.

Would that be the simplest way or should I look for something else?
Later I would also like to implement IF statements in the program.

Answer (score 0):

There surely are other ways to do this, but I would do it this way (just a  **basic** concept, you have to implement exception handling, unknown commands, illegal parameters and stuff like that...)

Command definition:

```
interface ICommand
{
    object Context { get; set; }
    bool IsResponsible(string line);
    void Execute(string line);
}
public class Move: ICommand
{
    public bool IsResponsible(string line)
    {
        return line.StartsWith("move");
    }
    public void Execute(string line)
    {
        var tmp = line.Split(',');
        // Validate and verify parameters here
        // code here to move the context to x/y 999.9
        // Context.Move(tmp[1], Convert.ToDouble(tmp[2]);
    }
}
public class Wait: ICommand
{
    public bool IsResponsible(string line)
    {
        return line.StartsWith("wait");
    }
    public void Execute(string line)
    {
        var tmp = line.Split(',');
        // code here to wait...
    }
}
```

Execution:

```
public void RunFile()
{
    var ctx = new YourContext();
    var commands = new List<IMyCommand>();
    // You could look for all ICommand implementations here with reflection or just hard-code all known classes...
    command.Add(new Move() { Context = ctx; });
    command.Add(new Wait() { Context = ctx; });

    var lines = File.ReadAllLines("your-file.txt");
    foreach(var line in lines)
    {
        var cmd = commands.FirstOrDefault(x => x.IsResponsible(line));
        if (cmd == null)
            throw new IOException("unknown command!");
        cmd.Execute(line);
    }
}
```

**not tested**

Comment: Thanks I got caught up in some other bussiness, I will check this out thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a functional language in your file format, then I would recommend using JSON over CSV.  JSON is very easy to parse .net (using the popular Newtonsoft.Json.dll nuget package), allows very human readable notation, and allows you flexibility that flat CSV simply can't offer.

The JSON equivalent of your CSV file would look something like this:

```
[
   {
      "command": "move",
      "axis": "x",
      "distance": 999.9
   },
   {
      "command": "wait",
      "interval": 1
   },  
   { 
      "command": "move",
      "axis": "y",
      "distance": 1.0
   },
   { 
      "command": "set",
      "valueName": "out",
      "newValue": 1
   }
]
```

Parsing this would be as easy as defining an object like this:

```
public class Command {
   [JsonProperty("command")]
   public string Command { get; set;}

   [JsonProperty("axis")]
   public string Axis { get; set;}

   [JsonProperty("distance")]
   public double Distance { get; set;}

   [JsonProperty("interval")]
   public double Interval { get; set;}

   [JsonProperty("valueName")]
   public string ValueName { get; set;}

   [JsonProperty("newValue")]
   public int NewValue { get; set;}
}

var commandList = JsonConvert.Deserialize<List<Command>>(rawTextOfCommandFile);
```

If you wanted to do your `IF` statement, just define an IF command that takes a conditional argument, a `THEN` argument, and an optional `ELSE` argument, where the `THEN` and `ELSE` arguments are typed as `Command` or `List<Command>`.  The markup would look like this:

```
[
   {
      "command": "if",
      "conditionValueName": "foo",
      "conditionValueOperator": "equals",
      "conditionValueOperand": "bar",
      "then": {
         "command": "move",
         "axis": "x",
         "distance": 1
      },
      "else": {
         "command": "move",
         "axis": "y",
         "distance": 3
      }
   }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

A lot of machines run g-code that do similar tasks, it's very simple http://linuxcnc.org/docs/html/gcode.html